# Crear usuario $webserver en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, autenticación, servicio

Hice un Servicio Web, usa autenticacion de windows, y necesito que tenga permisos en la base de datos de MSSQL

Hay otras bases de datos que tienen agregado un usuario "$webserver"

```
Security / Users / $WebServer
```

Estoy intentando agregar mi usuario de la misma manera, pero no, el usuario no es encontrado:

1.- Click derecho en Base de datos -> Security -> Users -> New User

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2.- En la ventana emergente -> `User Type` -> selecciono `Windows user`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3.- User Name selecciono el boton `...` y en la ventana emergente `Select User or Group` en `Locations` Selecciono `Entire Directory`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la misma ventana, en `Object Types` activo todos los cuadros:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ultimo, escribo `Dominio/$ServerName` y le doy en `Check Names`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y me sale este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si intento darle permisos a una carpeta del sistema de archivos al servidor, en Object Types me aparece este elemento que no aparece en MSSQL:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al darle en `Check Names`, me lo encuentra correctamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por que no me aparece el Objeto Computers en el cuadro de busqueda de usuario en MSSQL?

La respuesta a esto, supongo es por que MSSQL no quiere que agregue cuentas de servidor como usuarios. Por que?

Como puedo darle permisos a mi WebServer sobre mi base de datos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues simplemente agregue Dominio\ServerName$ en username y login sin buscar nada y le di OK y funciono.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Despues de eso no hay que olvidar darle permisos al usuario sobre la base de datos